# Continuous adding in calculator using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I've built a calculator using python and tkinter.

I cant figure out how to make it register several more than two numbers, for example if I enter 5 + 5 + 5 it won't show the result. But if i do 5+5 it will show 10.

```
from Tkinter import *
import math
class Calc():
def __init__(self):
    self.total=0
    self.current=""
    self.new_num=True
    self.op_pending=False
    self.op=""
    self.eq=False

def num_press(self,num):
    self.eq=False
    temp=e.get()
    temp2=str(num)
    if self.new_num:
        self.current=temp2
        self.new_num=False
    else:
        if temp2=='.':
            if temp2 in temp:
                return
        self.current=temp+temp2
    self.display(self.current)

def calc_total(self):
    self.eq=True
    self.current=float(self.current)
    if self.op_pending==True:
        self.do_sum()
    else:
        self.total=float(e.get())

def display(self,value):
    e.delete(0,END)
    e.insert(0,value)

def do_sum(self):
    if self.op=="add":
        self.total+=self.current
    if self.op=="minus":
        self.total-=self.current
    if self.op=="multi":
        self.total*=self.current
    if self.op=="div":
        self.total/=self.current
    self.new_num=True
    self.op_pending=False
    self.display(self.total)

def operation(self,op):
    self.current=float(self.current)
    if self.op_pending:
        self.do_sum()
    elif not self.eq:
        self.total=self.current
        self.new_num=True
        self.op_pending=True
        self.op=op
        self.eq=False

def clear(self):
    self.total=0
    self.display(self.total)

sum=Calc()
root=Tk()
root.geometry("410x270+200+200")
e = Entry(width=20)
e.grid(row=0,column=4)

b1= Button(text="1",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.num_press(1)).grid(row=0,column=0)

b2= Button(text="2",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.num_press(2)).grid(row=0,column=1)

#goes up to b9                                                                                                                                                           

equals= Button(text="=",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.calc_total()).grid(row=3,column=2)

add= Button(text="+",height=4,width=8,command=lambda: sum.operation("add")).grid(row=3,column=1)

minus= Button(text="-",height=4,width=8,command=lambda: sum.operation("minus")).grid(row=3,column=0)

multi= Button(text="*",height=4,width=8,command=lambda: sum.operation("multi")).grid(row=1,column=3)

div= Button(text="/",height=4,width=8,command=lambda: sum.operation("div")).grid(row=2,column=3) 

clear=Button(text="AC",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.clear()).grid(row=3,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by continuous?

Comment: if i press 5+5+5 it will show 5 and not 15, and if i press 5+5 it will show 10. like the maxium numbers i can do actions with are 2 only.

Answer (score 2):

To create a calculator that can do more than just calculate with 2 values, I would suggest using the [Shunting Yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm. With this, you can make a lot more complicated calculations, relatively easy.

Pseudocode source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

```
while there are tokens to be read:
    read a token.
    if the token is a number, then:
        push it to the output queue.
    if the token is a function then:
        push it onto the operator stack 
    if the token is an operator, then:
        while ((there is a function at the top of the operator stack)
               or (there is an operator at the top of the operator stack with greater precedence)
               or (the operator at the top of the operator stack has equal precedence and is left associative))
              and (the operator at the top of the operator stack is not a left bracket):
            pop operators from the operator stack onto the output queue.
        push it onto the operator stack.
    if the token is a left bracket (i.e. "("), then:
        push it onto the operator stack.
    if the token is a right bracket (i.e. ")"), then:
        while the operator at the top of the operator stack is not a left bracket:
            pop the operator from the operator stack onto the output queue.
        pop the left bracket from the stack.
        /* if the stack runs out without finding a left bracket, then there are mismatched parentheses. */
if there are no more tokens to read:
    while there are still operator tokens on the stack:
        /* if the operator token on the top of the stack is a bracket, then there are mismatched parentheses. */
        pop the operator from the operator stack onto the output queue.
exit.
```

To calculate an answer using this output:

1. take an operator from the ops stack, and according to the operator
2. take one or two elements from the operand stack, apply the operator
3. push the result and go back to 1. till done.